# Best way to show empty lists in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been working to follow the best practices in Rails in order to save time in the future.

I am displaying all terms in a view which has more than 0 results.

```
<% @terms.each do |t| %>
  <li class="media">
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="media-heading text-semibold"><%= link_to "#{t.name}", authenticated_root_path %></div>
      <span class="text-muted"><%= link_to 'Settings', edit_account_term_path(@account, t) %></span>
    </div>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

What is the best way to display a different view if the term count is zero? I could do something like a simple if statement in the view doing a count but that seems cluttered. Any suggestions?

Comment: why dont you simply use `pluralize` method instead of `if..else`..reference: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/pluralize

Comment: No other way. You need to use an if condition :-)

Comment: Yes, you can use the simple if..else statement , if @terms.count < 1 than show `<p>No terms available</p>` else show all term listing

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<% @terms.each do |t| %>
  <li class="media">
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="media-heading text-semibold"><%= link_to "#{t.name}", authenticated_root_path %></div>
      <span class="text-muted"><%= link_to 'Settings', edit_account_term_path(@account, t) %></span>
    </div>
  </li>
<% end.empty? and begin %>
  <li class="media">
    <!-- nothing to see -->
  </li>  
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also move the code to a partial.

```
<%= render(:partial => 'terms', :collection => @terms) || 'There are no terms' %>
```

The partial:

```
<li class="media">
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="media-heading text-semibold"><%= link_to "#{term.name}", authenticated_root_path %></div>
      <span class="text-muted"><%= link_to 'Settings', edit_account_term_path(@account, term) %></span>
    </div>
  </li>
</li>
```